# Get Currently Executing SQL Cursor statement

Tags: sql, loops, syntax, sql-server-2005, database-cursor

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190346.aspx

It says here in the section under the statement start/end offset that you can use that in conjunction with dm_exec_sql_text to get the currently executing cursor statement. What would be the command for that?

I have a fairly large SP that froze when it reached a cursor logic loop 'while (@@fetch_status =0) and I'd like to see if it is the exact executing statement I think it is, and I'd also like to see the parameters for this statement so I can see exactly why the cursor either never exited, or just why the statement inside the loop won't complete. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start with this

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT session_id,
     COALESCE(OBJECT_NAME(s2.objectid),'Ad-Hoc') AS ProcName,
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUBSTRING(s2.TEXT,statement_start_offset / 2+1 ,
      ( (CASE WHEN statement_end_offset = -1
         THEN (LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),s2.TEXT)) * 2)
         ELSE statement_end_offset END)  - statement_start_offset) / 2+1))  
       AS sql_statement
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS s1
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS s2 ) x
WHERE  sql_statement 
NOT like 'SELECT * FROM(SELECT session_id,COALESCE(%'
```